# Unable to read the node js request body in golang

Tags: node.js, go, axios

I'm using Golang to read the Node JS POST API, When I hitting it via postman it is working fine but via node js not works the log print **{"menPhoto": [Trading centr** only. I tried below steps but no use could any one help on it, Thanks.

**Request body**

```
{
    "menPhoto": [ //Dynamic key
        "Trading centre/TCXY7079/ASSES/9088c44x-c1ds-482r-8c4b-df2cc86f7b32_name.jpg"
    ],
    "womenPhoto": [ //Dynamic key
        "Trading centre/TCXY7080/ASSES/9088c44y-c1ds-482r-8c4b-df2cc86f7b32_name.jpg"
    ],
    "menIDPhoto": [ //Dynamic key
        "Trading centre/TCXX7080/ASSES/9088c44y-c1ds-482r-8c4b-df2cc86f7b32_name.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Node JS

```
getImages: gI => {
axios.post(config.dcmtService, reqUrls, {
  headers: headers
}).then((response) => {

})
}
```

GoLang

First try

```
var data map[string]interface{} or map[string][]string 
err = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&data)
fmt.Println("1=============>>>>", data) //empty
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("GetSignedURLs err " + err.Error())
}
```

Second try

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Error reading request body", http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

fmt.Println("Request body string:", string(body))
Response - {"menPhoto": [Trading centr
```

Third try with encodeURIComponent (in node js end)

```
Node
-------------------------------------------------------
const encodedString = encodeURIComponent(reqUrls);
getImages: gI => {
axios.post(config.dcmtService, encodedString, {
  headers: headers
}).then((response) => {

})
}
 
Golang
---------------------------------
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Error reading request body", http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

decodedString, err := url.QueryUnescape(string(body))
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

fmt.Println("Decoded string:", decodedString)

var data map[string]interface{}
err = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&data)
fmt.Println("1=============>>>>", data)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("GetSignedURLs err " + err.Error())
}
Response - {"menPhoto": [Trading centr
```

Comment: You are not encoding the body correctly on the JavaScript side. The quotes around the strings are missing. The error returned by Decode should report that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unmarshal :

```
type JsonRsp struct {
    MenPhoto     []string          `json:"menPhoto"`
    WomenPhoto   []string          `json:"womenPhoto"`
    MenIDPhoto   []string          `json:"menIDPhoto"`
}

jsonResult := JsonRsp{}

body, err := io.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    return
}

err = json.Unmarshal(body, &jsonResult)
if err != nil {
    return
}

fmt.Println("menPhoto:", jsonResult.MenPhoto[0])
```

Comment: but all fields are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following. you can replace `strings.NewReader(data)` with r.Body in your code

```
 package main

 import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
 )

var data = `{
"menPhoto": [  
    "Trading centre/TCXY7079/ASSES/9088c44x-c1ds-482r-8c4b-df2cc86f7b32_name.jpg"
],
"womenPhoto": [  
    "Trading centre/TCXY7080/ASSES/9088c44y-c1ds-482r-8c4b-df2cc86f7b32_name.jpg"
],
"menIDPhoto": [  
    "Trading centre/TCXX7080/ASSES/9088c44y-c1ds-482r-8c4b-df2cc86f7b32_name.jpg"
]
 }`

 func main() {
  body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(strings.NewReader(data))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

var response map[string]interface{}
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &response)
if err != nil {
    return
}
fmt.Println("1=============>>>>", response)
}
```

check the goplayground i created here
https://go.dev/play/p/QxmYO7kOYCh